# I created the method but I can't call it in main

Tags: java, methods

I want to call the method calculationsMethod from main to perform the calculations and display the results but I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaHomework1 {

static void calculationsMethod() {
   Float perimeter = ((2*length) + (2*breadth));
   Float area = ((length*breadth));
   System.out.println("The Perimeter of the Rectangle is " + perimeter);
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the length of the rectangle: ");
    Float length = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Input the breadth of the rectangle: ");
    Float breadth = input.nextFloat(); 
    input.close();
    // I want to send length and breadth to the above method for the calculation
    calculationsMethod(); // then call the method for displaying the results
    
}

}
```

Comment: Your variables only exist in the scope of `main()`. You'll need to pass them as arguments or declare them as fields if you want to access them in `calculationsMethod()`.

Comment: There's no [TL;DR](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath#tldr) at this point, you need to read about java basics :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your variables only existed in the scope of `main()`, the only thing missing was declaring them as fields in the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stack {

    //You did not declare them or call them to the method, 
    //so that's why your method didn't recognise length or breadth
static void calculationsMethod(Float length, Float breadth) {
   Float perimeter = ((2*length) + (2*breadth));
   Float area = ((length*breadth));
   System.out.println("The Perimeter of the Rectangle is " + perimeter);
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the length of the rectangle: ");
    Float length = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Input the breadth of the rectangle: ");
    Float breadth = input.nextFloat(); 
    input.close();
    //So basically your length and breadth only existed in the scope of main().
    calculationsMethod(length, breadth); 
    
}

}
```

This works:

[image: This is it working!]